# Where is the checkedRadioButtonId attribute on Android'd official doc?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to phone app dev, so Android Kotlin dev is totally new to me.  I am in a training session provided by the official android site.

The line below uses binding to access a selected radio button in a radio group.

```
val selectedId = binding.tipOptions.checkedRadioButtonId
```

I couldn't find `checkedRadioButtonId` attribute in my XML file.  Instead, my XML file and the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup#attr_android:checkedButton) has only `android:checkedButton`. Anyone know where `checkedRadioButtonId` is from?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`binding.tipOptions` is a `RadioGroup` in your xml layout file. the `RadioGroup.java` has a function named `getCheckedRadioButtonId()`. On kotlin it can be used like `checkedRadioButtonId`, because kotlin getter and setter syntax: [getters-and-setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters)